# How to Search a CSV file for a String and get It's Row Index In Python 2.7

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to open a csv and search the 1st column for an Email. If it exist, then check if the 3rd Column of that specific row = '1'. I can't Figure out how to Check ONLY the 3rd column of the row that has the Email in it. Is there a way that I can get the Index of the row, that the Email is in? then I could do something like row[Row #][2], so it would search column 3 of the row with the Email. Here's what I have right now:

```
with open('MyFile.csv', 'rb') as f:     
    reader = list(csv.reader(f))
    for row in reader:
        if Email in row[0]:   #checks if email exist
            if '1' in row[2]:   #searches every row instead of just the one with email
                print "Account Already = 1"
```

How can I add something like this:

```
with open('MyFile.csv', 'rb') as f:     
    reader = list(csv.reader(f))
    for row in reader:
        if Email in row[0]:
            print Email.index
            #(lets say it returns '4')
            if '1' in row[3][2]:   #searches only 4th row for '1' 
                quit()
```

EDIT-- I got it working, this is what i'm using:

```
df =pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

a = np.where((df['Email'] == Email) & (df['Num'] == '1'))
try:
    if (a[0][0] + 1) > 0:
    print "Account = 1"
    quit()
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: `row[4]` is the fifth column of the current row, and `row[4][2]` is the third character of the fifth column. Didn't you want to check the third column? (`row[2]`)

Comment: @DYZ  yes thanks, I edited the question. I accidentally went up 1 instead of down.

Comment: `row[3]` is still not the third column, but the fourth. Also, you probably do not need the `[2]` part, simply check `if row[2]=='1'`.

Comment: @DYZ  4th row and 3rd Column, I didn't know if the order is row/column or column/row

Comment: `row` is your _current_ row. `reader` is a list of all rows that have been read. So, `reader[3][2]=='1'`.

Comment: @DYZ how would I get the index of the row with the Email though?

Comment: You can step through the pairs of row indexes and rows with `enumerate` and save the index of interest into a variable when you come across it: `for idx,row in enumerate(reader): ...` (By the way, the previous line is not necessary, you can do `for idx,row in enumerate(csv.reader(file)): ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv')

np.where((df['email_column_name']=='email_to_lookup@email.com') & (df['3rd column name']== '1'))
```

Comment: works great! I updated my question with the code i'm using now, would you make any changes?

Comment: @sorry I didn't quite get what you mean. What do you expect me to change?

Comment: sorry, I commented before I updated the question. I just didn't know if there was a cleaner way to do what I was doing.

Comment: oh, right, since you've copied the answer to your question, I will leave my answer unchanged as it's more generic. would you accept this as your answer?